# Change the slug of post type using custom code

Tags: posts, permalinks

How can the default `post` post type permalink slug be modified to add `/blog`? Without changing other post types

Comment: Are you referring to Posts? The Posts post type doesn't have a slug in the URL for you to change. If you want to add something to the URL, such as /news, you can do this in the permalinks settings by adding it to your permalinks structure. Anything added will only be added to posts, not pages.

Comment: https://www.scienceinthecity.org.mt/press-release/. this the link i want to look like this https://www.scienceinthecity.org.mt/blog/press-release/. it is possible ?

Comment: So just add blog/ to your permalink structure in Settings > Permalinks.

Comment: but it will affect the all post right ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called [`wp_unique_post_slug`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_unique_post_slug/) which is called whenever you save a post. This function contains a filter of the same name that you can use to modify the slug, depending on, for instance, the post type. This example will prepend the slug with the post type, so you can see from the slug which type a post belongs to:

```
add_filter ('wp_unique_post_slug','wpse420126_change_slug', 10, 6);

function wpse420126_change_slug ($slug, $post_id, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent, $original_slug) {
  return $post_type . '-' . $slug;
  }
```

Comment: function custom_post_permalink($permalink, $post, $leavename) {
    // Check if the post type is 'post'
    if ($post->post_type == 'post') {
        // Customize the URL structure here
        $permalink = '/blog/' . $post->post_name . '/';
    }

    return $permalink;
}

add_filter('pre_post_link', 'custom_post_permalink', 10, 3);

this is my code. and its working but, if go to inner page of the post i publish it will show the page not found.

Comment: i have single.php in ftp.

Comment: `pre_post_link` filters the permalink when you retrieve it. So if you use this filter to change the slug to something that does not exist, it will render a 404. Also, this should be in `functions.php`.